# visual studio individual settings for typescript file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

In my visual studio project properties I have enabled checkbox "Combine JavaScript output into file". 
Can I exclude some typescript files from this output? I want compile this (excluded) files to individual js files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in my case is modify csproj:

1. Change file target from

```
 <TypeScriptCompile Include="file.ts" />
```

to

```
 <CustomTypeScriptCompile Include="file.ts" />
```

2. Add "CustomTypeScriptCompile" target:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomCompileTsFiles>@(CustomTypeScriptCompile->'%(FullPath)')</CustomCompileTsFiles>
    <SplitedCompileTsFiles>$(CustomCompileTsFiles.Replace(';', ' '))</SplitedCompileTsFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="CustomTypeScriptCompile" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="tsc $(SplitedCompileTsFiles) --sourcemap -t ES5" />
    </Target>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. After editing this into my project file, how could I mark a given `.ts` file for separate compilation?

Comment: Change build action in file properties to "CustomTypeScriptCompile"

Comment: Thanks Igor, this could be very useful for web-workers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not do it via VS project and .ts files settings.

You can use grunt task runner extension (described in the [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingGulpGruntBowerAndNpmSupportForVisualStudio.aspx)) + grunt-typescript plugin for custom TypeScript build task, "gruntfile.js" sample content:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    typescript: {
        buildmodules: {
            src: ['modules/*.ts'],
            dest: 'bin/modules.js',
            options: {
                module: 'amd', //or commonjs
                target: 'es5', //or es3
                basePath: 'path/to/typescript/files',
                sourceMap: true,
                declaration: true
            }
        },
        tests: {
            src: ['Tests/*.ts'],
            dest: 'bin/tests.js',
            options: {
                module: 'amd', //or commonjs
                target: 'es5', //or es3
                basePath: 'path/to/typescript/files',
                sourceMap: true,
                declaration: true
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-typescript");
```

Also you can use Web Essentials extension for bundling separate .js files produced by TSC.